Does React modal window always causes parent's re-render?
I have developed a modal window with React several times and have always faced the problem of re-rendering the parent component.
For example, I am currently using MUI and react-transition-group to work with a modal window. I hoped that the modal windows provided by MUI would solve this problem, but it remains.
It's always a setState in parent component for opening modal and for closing modal.
Are such re-renders a serious problem and if they are, how to solve it?
// parent component - predictably uses a useState
const Intro = () => {
   // useModal - returns state and setState functions
   const {isOpened, handleOpen, handleClose} = useModal(); 

   return (
      <Box className={styles.intro}>
         // ...
               <Button variant="contained" sx={overrideButtons.contained} onClick={handleOpen}>
                  Text
               </Button>
         </Container>

         // *** the modal ***
         // there is a button that uses handleClose inside
         <FullScreenDialog isOpened={isOpened} handleClose={handleClose}/>

      </Box>
   );


Everytime you want to update something on UI, you have to perform re-renders. In React, when state or props change in a component, React re-renders that component and its child components using a process called reconciliation. This means that React compares the new virtual DOM with the previous one to determine what needs to be updated in the actual DOM.
Therefore, in React, one must make sure that there should be minimal number of re-renders( the re-renders that can be justified).
Lastly, you should also make sure that re-render size should be small by isolating the component as deep as you can. In your case, you can separate out the modal into it's own component in order to avoid re-rendering the whole parent.

Yes, i know, but how can i avoid re-renders when i'm changing state in parent component? The only option i see is place call of useModal and modal component in some another place (maybe inside button which triggers modal window, if modal component uses portal)
